# Why is my rotation not working?

Tags: complex-numbers, rotations

I have complex data (a+bi) and when I plot without rotating I get
[Unrotated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAskw.png)

But when I try to rotate using 
$x' = x*cos(\theta) - y*sin(\theta)$ and 
$y' = y*cos(\theta) + x*sin(\theta)$

I get this [Rotated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnXA5.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What *exactly* are you entering? The formula for rotating $(x,y)$ to $(x',y')$ is correct, but I don't know how you are relating it to $a+bi$, and we can't tell what your mistake is unless you tell us exactly what you are doing.

Comment: The data is in the form (a,b) and that's how it's plotted

Comment: Where do you derive the rotation angle from? What is $θ$ in relation to the given data?

Comment: @boson Ok, that answers my second question, but there is still a lot left to explain about what exactly you're doing to plot it.

Comment: Show us your code and we'll spot the bug. My bet is premature assignment of $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data are for a curve in polar coordinates, $$a(t)+ib(t)=r(t)e^{iθ(t)},$$
then you probably want to trace 
\begin{align}
r&=e^{-iθ}(a+ib)
\\
&=\bigl(\cos(θ)a+\sin(θ)b\bigr)+i\bigl(\cos(θ)b-\sin(θ)a\bigr).
\end{align}

If you compute $θ$ as the argument of $a+ib$, be sure to correct for the right quadrant when using the arcus tangent function, or use the often available argument function `theta=atan2(b,a)`.